# TikZ scatter plot: continuous function to discrete approximation

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot a Geometric distribution PMF and I know I could just manually construct a table for discrete values, but I was looking for something less exhaustive and more accurate. So I got a scatter plot of PMF (initially treated as continuous function) and now I want to connect the points with straight lines. Is there a way to do this, or you have to store the actual points in table? If so, is there any way to automatically calculate function values for the table?

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
        declare function={
            geom(\x,\p) = \p * (1-\p)^(\x);
        },
   }
       \pgfplotsset{exp_chart/.style={
        height=9cm, width=18cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-0.05,
        ymax=1.2,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$f(x)$},
        xtick = {0.5, 1, ..., 4.5},
        ytick = {0.5, 1},
        axis line style = thick,
        axis lines = middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
   }}
   
   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[exp_chart, ymax=1.2]
        \addplot[color=red, domain=0:4, samples=5, only marks] {geom(x,0.5)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm missing anything here, but you have `only marks`, meaning you get only the marks. If you remove that you get a line plot, if you replace it with `mark=*` you get line and markers.

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Can you convert your comment into a response?

Comment: @AndréC Done ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `only marks` in the options to the `\addplot`, which means that only the markers are plotted, like a scatter plot. If you remove `only marks` you'll get a solid line without markers. If you replace it with `mark=*` you get both markers and line.

Hence, `\addplot[color=red, domain=0:4, samples=5, mark=*] {geom(x,0.5)};` gives

[image]

Note by the way that with `width=18cm` you get a plot that is wider than the text block, so you get an overfull hbox warning.

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\tikzset{
        declare function={
            geom(\x,\p) = \p * (1-\p)^(\x);
        },
   }
       \pgfplotsset{exp_chart/.style={
        height=9cm, width=18cm,
        xmin=0, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-0.05,
        ymax=1.2,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$f(x)$},
        xtick = {0.5, 1, ..., 4.5},
        ytick = {0.5, 1},
        axis line style = thick,
        axis lines = middle,
        enlargelimits=false,
   }}
   
\begin{document}

   \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[exp_chart, ymax=1.2]
        \addplot[color=red, domain=0:4, samples=5, mark=*] {geom(x,0.5)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```